# Installing Ruby 2.3 on WSL (Windows Subsystem for Linux)

Tags: ruby, windows, rbenv, windows-subsystem-for-linux

First off, sorry for my bad English.

I'm trying to install Ruby 2.3.0 on my system with rbenv via Windows Subsystem for Linux aka Ubuntu on Windows 10. I followed [this](https://medium.com/@hleclerc/use-rbenv-ruby-on-windows-10-linux-wsl-a9bce8d97300#.odahsflp2) instruction (but not 100% exactly). but every time I try, It fails to build Ruby with this log.

```
check struct members..
check libraries....
Use ActiveTcl libraries (if available).
Search tclConfig.sh and tkConfig.sh..............................
Fail to find [tclConfig.sh, tkConfig.sh]
Use X11 libraries (or use TK_XINCLUDES/TK_XLIBSW information on tkConfig.sh).
Warning:: cannot find X11 library. tcltklib will not be compiled (tcltklib is disabled on your Ruby. That is, Ruby/Tk will not work). Please check configure options. If your Tcl/Tk don't require X11, please try --without-X11.
Can't find X11 libraries. 
So, can't make tcltklib.so which is required by Ruby/Tk.
Failed to configure tk. It will not be installed.
Failed to configure tk/tkutil. It will not be installed.
configuring zlib
make[1]: Entering directory `/tmp/ruby-build.20160522033606.7696/ruby-2.3.1'
make -C ext/digest/sha2 -w --jobserver-fds=6,7 -j V= realclean
make[2]: Entering directory `/tmp/ruby-build.20160522033606.7696/ruby-2.3.1/ext/digest/sha2'
Makefile:39: *** missing separator.  Stop.
make[2]: Leaving directory `/tmp/ruby-build.20160522033606.7696/ruby-2.3.1/ext/digest/sha2'
make[1]: *** [ext/digest/sha2/realclean] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/tmp/ruby-build.20160522033606.7696/ruby-2.3.1'
make: *** [build-ext] Error 2
```

and this is my installed package list

```
libx11-data/trusty,now 2:1.6.2-1ubuntu2 all [installed]
libx11-dev/trusty,now 2:1.6.2-1ubuntu2 amd64 [installed]
libx11-doc/trusty,now 2:1.6.2-1ubuntu2 all [installed,automatic]
libx11-xcb1/trusty,now 2:1.6.2-1ubuntu2 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libtk8.4/trusty,now 8.4.20-7 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libtcl8.4/trusty,now 8.4.20-7 amd64 [installed,automatic]
```

As you see, I installed X11, tcl, tk but my system can't detect them. 
Have I done wrong? or it is just a bug?

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 33):

My installation follow this tutorial, go there for most recent update: [link here](https://gorails.com/setup/windows/10).

### **1. Install Ruby**

First some dependencies for Ruby:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install git-core curl zlib1g-dev build-essential libssl-dev libreadline-dev libyaml-dev libsqlite3-dev sqlite3 libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev libcurl4-openssl-dev software-properties-common libffi-dev
```

Now for Ruby: there are 3 ways to install, each way conflict with each other, so choose one you think fit yours most or my suggestion: `rbenv`

**Using rbenv (recommend)**

```
cd
git clone https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv.git ~/.rbenv
echo 'export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bashrc
echo 'eval "$(rbenv init -)"' >> ~/.bashrc
exec $SHELL

git clone https://github.com/rbenv/ruby-build.git ~/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build
echo 'export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bashrc
exec $SHELL

rbenv install 2.3.1
rbenv global 2.3.1
ruby -v
```

**Using `rvm`**

```
sudo apt-get install libgdbm-dev libncurses5-dev automake libtool bison libffi-dev
gpg --keyserver hkp://keys.gnupg.net --recv-keys 409B6B1796C275462A1703113804BB82D39DC0E3
curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable
source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm
rvm install 2.3.1
rvm use 2.3.1 --default
ruby -v
```

**From the source**

```
cd
wget http://ftp.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/2.3/ruby-2.3.1.tar.gz
tar -xzvf ruby-2.3.1.tar.gz
cd ruby-2.3.1/
./configure
make
sudo make install
ruby -v
```

After install Ruby, install Bundler

```
gem install bundler
```

### **2. Install Rails**

First you need NodeJS:

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_4.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

Then install rails:

```
gem install rails -v 4.2.6
```

If you're using `rbenv`, you'll need to run the following command to make the rails executable available:

```
rbenv rehash
```

Now that you've installed Rails, you can run the rails -v command to make sure you have everything installed correctly:

```
rails -v
# Rails 4.2.6
```

### 3. Install DB

MySQL:

You can install MySQL server and client from the packages in the Ubuntu repository. As part of the installation process, you'll set the password for the root user. This information will go into your Rails app's database.yml file in the future.

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server mysql-client libmysqlclient-dev
```

PostgreSQL:

Currently, some bug prevents you from installing Postgres correctly, so I recommend you MySQL for now.

```
sudo sh -c "echo 'deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ xenial-pgdg main' > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list"
wget --quiet -O - http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ACCC4CF8.asc | sudo apt-key add -
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install postgresql-common
sudo apt-get install postgresql-9.5 libpq-dev
```

The Postgres installation doesn't setup a user for you, so you'll need to follow these steps to create a user with permission to create databases. Feel free to replace chris with your username.

```
sudo -u postgres createuser chris -s

# If you would like to set a password for the user, you can do the following
sudo -u postgres psql
postgres=# \password chris
```

### Final Steps

Now make sure things go right not left

```
#### If you want to use SQLite (not recommended)
rails new myapp

#### If you want to use MySQL
rails new myapp -d mysql

#### If you want to use Postgres
# Note that this will expect a postgres user with the same username
# as your app, you may need to edit config/database.yml to match the
# user you created earlier
rails new myapp -d postgresql

# Move into the application directory
cd myapp

# If you setup MySQL or Postgres with a username/password, modify the
# config/database.yml file to contain the username/password that you specified

# Create the database
rake db:create

rails server
```

Comment: I'd recommend verbose logging on the rbenv and rvm install steps.  Many are reporting _very_ long install times of 30 minutes or more.  Verbose logging can provide piece of mind that the process isn't hung.

Comment: This doesn't work it says `E: Package 'python-software-properties' has no installation candidate`

Comment: Seem that it changed to `software-properties-common`. Thanks for the notices. Updated!

Comment: Pretty good answer, but note that the question was not about Rails. People do use Ruby without it.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have updated your Windows installation - run 'Windows 10 Upgrade Assistant' and install the Windows 10 Creators Update. Anything before this is riddled with bugs and my `rbenv` Rails install wouldn't work. If it still won't work after updating Windows to CU then you can always just use `rvm` instead. You may need to reinstall everything anyway, as its recommended to reinstall/upgrade Ubuntu if you are using WSL.